# OpenNI Body Gesture Recognnition?

Tags: openni

I was wondering of there is a way for OpenNI to recognize a movement such as crouching or running in place? And could you have hand, finger and body recognition all running at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played with [pose estimation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qESgiIWavk8&list=UU04-FQBwnGPfIc8W8KDRFHQ&index=6&feature=plcp) a while back, but that's not the same as gesture recognition which also involves time.

I recommend having a look at [Dynamic Time Warping(DTW)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) as a useful technique.
Also have a look at the [KineticSpace project](http://code.google.com/p/kineticspace/) which makes use of this technique.
It's written in Processing(Java) and uses a wrapper, but it still uses OpenNI under the hood.
[image: kinectic space]

This should  help you work out crouching and perhaps running.
Regarding your second question: you get body recognition and hand tracking for free with OpenNI/Nite, but you'd have to do the finger detection yourself.
Here are few random results found on Google:

- [Kinect Core Vision](http://patriciogonzalezvivo.com/2011/kinectcorevision/)
- [Finger Tip on CodePlex](http://fingertip.codeplex.com/)
- [ROS Finger tracking](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Finger%20Detector) 
  There are more examples out there, it depends on what language you use and how comfortable you are coding.

HTH

Comment: But if this project is coded in java, how would one implement its recognition techniques into an objective-c++ code?

Comment: If you mean the Kinetic Space part, most of the effort will probably go into porting `DTW.pde` (which contains the implementation of the DTW algo) and `Data.pde` (which contains the serialization part of code - saving/loading custom gestures). Most of the other code relates to key events and OpenNI events (for skeleton/user detection and tracking) - which can be easily be ported to C++ and the main part application mostly makes uses of float/int arrays which again are trivial to port. I've used OpenNI in c++ as well(standalone and with OpenCV) but I haven't used OpenNI with objective-c++...

Comment: If you're planning to use that and never used Processing before I recommend [downloading](http://processing.org/download/) it and [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/list) as well - running and exploring the project. Initially, personally, I'd start removing the parts I don't need and end up with the simplest piece of code that has the DTW functionality I need then I'd carry on porting class by class and testing each, then putting together a simple demo that makes use of the classes. Finally I'd integrate the simplified/abstracted ported code with the main project.

Comment: Well objective-c++ is c++ with another library linked so no diffrence

Comment: And who wants to port java to c++ two languages i hate, no offense, but c++ is very similart to java which i cant stand, isnt there a diffrent project written in c?

Comment: You asked if the project is coded in java, how would you implement in objective-c. I've just supplied a simple project that's all, the **main** thing to take away is the DTW algorithm which you can either search for a c implementation or simply code your own using the explanations/pseudo-code from the wiki link. Totally up to what best fits you, of course :)

Comment: And where did i mention java? We both know that openni has java backend but i never mentioned java i mentioned c languages, and forget the objective part, its just linking an extra library, no diffrence

Comment: I found out about c++/objective c++ by asking you. Your original question does not mention any language and doesn't any language tag, therefore I assumed language isn't really the issue, a decent algorithm is :)